# Can't get laser_base data on a distant machine

Tags: ros, pr2, base-laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I work with PR2 which runs on ubuntu 12.4 and ros Groovy. I am trying to get Hokuyo base laser data from a machine under ubuntu which is not the base station.
I ran a robot start on an admin account (logged with ssh)  and then tried to get the laser data using "rostopic echo /base_scan" on my machine. The node waits indefinitly, giving no data.
When I run "rostopic echo /base_scan" from the ssh connected to the robot: I correctly receive the data.

I think it may be a setup problem with ROS yet we can see the image_view of the camera from my machine using "$rosrun image_view image_view image=:/wide_stereo/left/image_color"

I checked all the environments variables:
ROS_IP=my_IP and ROS_MASTER_URI= robot_IP.
On the dashboard, there is no warning messages about lasers.

When I run "roswtf" I get:

ERROR: connection refused to [10.68.0.1:59682/]

ERROR: Unknown host [pr1043s] for node [/two_hd_monitor]

ERROR: Unknown host [pr1043s] for node [/two_cpu_monitor]

ERROR: Unknown host [pr1043s] for node [/joy]

ERROR: Unknown host [pr1043s] for node [/base_hokuyo_node]

ERROR: Unknown host [pr1043s] for node [/tilt_hokuyo_node]

ERROR: Unknown host [pr1043s] for node [/ocean_server]

ERROR: connection refused to [10.68.0.1:57249/]

ERROR: Unknown host [pr1043s] for node [/ntp_c2]

Where I recognize hokuyo laser but I don't know how to solve the problem.

Anyone ever encoutered this problem? What can I do to get more infos about my problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/130276/can%27t-get-laser_base-data-on-a-distant-machine/) by [scarlett](https://answers.ros.org/users/12086/scarlett/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2014-02-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like your network isn't set up properly. In particular, due to the way networking is set up on the PR2, and due to the fact that it's doing remote launches for all of the nodes that run on the secondary computer, you absolutely should not be setting ROS_IP on your PR2.

Instead, you should make sure that any machines on your network can resolve the PR2's DNS names (presumably pr1043 and pr1043s) to the IP addresses that are configured in /etc/robot-forward.conf on the basestation.

For more information, take a look at the [Basestation Setup Tutorial](http://pr2support.willowgarage.com/wiki/Tutorials/ConfiguringBasestation) for an overview of how to set up your basestation, and [Chapter 12 of the PR2 Manual](http://pr2support.willowgarage.com/wiki/PR2%20Manual/Chapter12) for a deeper description of how the network setup on the PR2 works.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1